# JAX does jitting functions separately change performances?

Tags: jit, jax

I am learning to use JAX and I have some doubts about the use of `jit` and `vmap` that I couldn't solve by reading the docs.

1. Does it make a difference to `jit` several functions separately and then `jit` the function that uses them? For example, if I have the functions `foo()` and `bar()` and a function

   ```py
   @jax.jit 
   def fooBar(x):
       return foo(x) + bar(x)
   ```

   Is there any difference if `foo()` and `bar()` are already jitted?
2. Should I `jit` a function after I `vmap` it? In the example above, should I do `jax.jit(jax.vmal(fooBar))` or just `jax.vmap(fooBar)`?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to performance of code execution, there is no difference between jitting functions separately and jitting once at the outer function (functionally there is one subtle difference: jit-compiling the inner function will wrap the contents in an `xla_call` primitive, but this makes little to no difference for the final compilation & execution).

When using `vmap` on the other hand, there is no implicit compilation. `vmap(f)` will be executed in eager mode, while `jit(vmap(f))` will be just-in-time compiled and generally result in faster execution.